# F# can't invoke Seq.fold without piping?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I'm busy learning F# and was playing around with `Seq.fold`. Could anyone explain why the following two invocations are not essentially the same and one errors and the other does not.

Invoking this way:

```
Seq.fold (fun state input -> state + input) 0 Seq.ofList [1;2;3;4;5];;
```

Results in the following error:

```
error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    ''a -> 'b'
but here has type
    'int'
```

Invoking with piping works fine:

```
Seq.ofList [1;2;3;4;5] |> Seq.fold (fun state input -> state + input) 0;;
```

I'm guessing I've somehow taken a generic function and forced it to be int only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're passing Seq.ofList as the 3rd parameter to Seq.fold.  You need to add some parens:

`Seq.fold (fun state input -> state + input) 0 (Seq.ofList [1;2;3;4;5]);;`

Comment: I can only say "Doh!". Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Seq.ofList is not mandatory.
You can directly write:

```
Seq.fold (fun state input -> state + input) 0 [1;2;3;4;5]
```

or:

```
[1;2;3;4;5] |> Seq.fold (fun state input -> state + input) 0
```